# Check-in when flying as a minor? (American)

Tags: air-travel, american-airlines, minors

Current college freshman in the US who will be traveling across the country this summer for an internship. Only catch: I will be one month shy of my 18th birthday during my arrival flight. I am flying with American, and from what I can tell from their website, there are certain restrictions for unaccompanied minors. However, it seems like these restrictions apply *only* when using their unaccompanied minor program.

Does this mean that I can just show up and check-in by myself?

(Other details: Domestic, daytime flight. One connection.)

Comment: At 17 there are no restrictions and special rules. You will be treated no different then a regular adult.My kids have done international trips by themselves starting at 15 or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly. It is possible to purchase [unaccompanied minor service](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/unaccompanied-minors.jsp) for a 17-year-old on American, where airline employees will escort you from place to place and ensure you only leave with a designated adult who shows ID. Since you're a college student headed off to an internship, that doesn't sound like a service you want or need.

You can simply check in the same way as any adult.